# Undefined reference to SDL_*many*

Tags: c++, sdl

This is my makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g -lSDL -lSDL_image
CC = g++
OBJ = Point.o Personaje.o Juego.o EventHandler.o

all: main

#%.o: %.cpp %.h
#   $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

bin: other $(OBJ)

Point.o: Point.cpp Point.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

Personaje.o: Personaje.cpp Personaje.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

Juego.o: Juego.cpp Juego.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

EventHandler.o: EventHandler.cpp EventHandler.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

main: $(OBJ)
    cd ../vista/; make
    cp ../vista/*.o .
    rm ../vista/*.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) Pantalla.o Imagen.o main.cpp -o main

clean:
    rm *.o;
    rm main

PHONY: main
```

When I compile with "make" I get the following errors:

```
EventHandler.cpp:17: undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
Pantalla.o: In function `Pantalla::initialize(int, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
Pantalla.cpp:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
Pantalla.cpp:9: undefined reference to `SDL_SetVideoMode'
Pantalla.cpp:14: undefined reference to `SDL_WM_SetCaption'
```

and many other errors.

The header of "Pantalla.h" contains this line:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
```

And I already installed the SDL packages.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... please help!

Comment: Make sure you mark one of the answers below as correct.  It's been 5 hours, and you should click the "checkbox" near one of the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g -lSDL -lSDL_image
```

This isn't good. You're mixing compiler flags (warnings and debug) with linker information (which libraries you need to link to). Use two separate variables for that:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g
LIBS = -lSDL -lSDL_image
```

Then when you compile (but don't link, i.e. when you generate the `.o` files), only use `$(CFLAGS)` (like you have now). But when you do link (to produce the final executable), add the linker directives.

```
g++ $(CFLAGS) -o main main.cpp $(OBJ) Pantalla.o Imagen.o $(LIBS)
```

The order you put your objects and libraries *is important*.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you are using exactly the same flags for compilation and linking. The compiler doesn't use libraries; the linker doesn't know about pedantic.

A bigger problem is that your `-lSDL -lSDL_image` appears too early in the link command, `g++ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) Pantalla.o Imagen.o main.cpp -o main`.  The linker won't look into libSDL.a or libSDL_image.a (or their equivalents) because there are no unresolved external references at the point where you specified the search. Put the `-lSDL -lSDL_image` options just before the `-o` option.